# Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a cursowWindow

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have a problem with this function.

```
 public ArrayList<Integer> getStopId(long line_id) {

    String selectQuery = "SELECT _ID_STOP FROM TIME WHERE _ID_LINE = " + line_id;
    ArrayList<Integer> stopID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst())
        do {

            stopID.add(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_ID_STOP")));

        } while (c.moveToNext());

    return stopID;
 }
```

I would like to get a table stopID that contains all the values of the rows of the query selectQuery. It returns a table of 1 column and 24 rows.

When I launch my application, it says "Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a cursowWindow which has 24 rows, 1 columns.

Thanks for you help !

Comment: your getStopId should return a Cursor, not ArrayList, your data model is sqlite db so use its native interfaces

Comment: @pskink Long-running transactions might not be a good idea.

Comment: I think the Problem could be that You wrote while(c.moveToNext()), try while(!c.isAfterLast());

Comment: please post the size of your cursor (`c.getCount()`) and also the current position (`c.getPosition()`) of your cursor at the moment you are trying to retrieve the value.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs `moveToNext` already returns the correct value, and without moving to the next record, the loop would never end.

Comment: @rogcg As shown in the error message, it's the first of 24 rows. The problem is the *column* number.

Comment: @CL. does query() begin the transaction?

Comment: @pskink Yes; and it cannot end before the cursor is closed.

Comment: The problem is that it might be looking for a row identifier (i.e. BaseColumns#_ID) and not finding it in the cursor. In all queries, the column `_id` must be specified. Try changing your query to `"SELECT _id, _ID_STOP FROM TIME WHERE _ID_LINE = " + line_id`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @CL. run db.query() method, iterate over returned Cursor and Log.d db.inTransaction()

Comment: I replaced c.getColumnIndex("_ID_STOP") by 0 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @user3636812 if you are not sure about column names use DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor or dumpCurrentRow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was :

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getStopId(long line_id) {

String selectQuery = "SELECT _ID_STOP FROM TIME WHERE _ID_LINE = " + line_id;
ArrayList<Integer> stopID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

if (c.moveToFirst())
    do {

        stopID.add(c.getInt(0));

    } while (c.moveToNext());

return stopID;
 }
```

I just replaced c.getColumnIndex("_ID_STOP") by 0 and it worked perfectly.